# PrincipalServerDownException on Windows XP but not on Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, active-directory, windows-xp, principalcontext

We have a WPF application that runs in full trust.

Part of the application checks the membership of a Windows AD group.

This works fine on a Windows 7 machine, but not on a Windows XP machine.

The error occurs on the following line:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain name");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx), the "domain name" variable might not be needed. That is, if you are accessing an Active Directory in the same domain as your application, the domain name is not needed.

> You use the name parameter on the PrincipalContext constructor in
>   order to provide the name of the specific directory to connect to.
>   This can be the name of a specific server, machine, or domain. It's
>   important to note that if this parameter is null, AccountManagement
>   will attempt to determine a default machine or domain for the
>   connection based on your current security context.

The solution or workaround to the problem (at least what worked for me on both XP and W7) is the following change:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null);
```